# Iteratively compare one element to all others in a Python list

Tags: python, list

I want to compare every element of the list to the rest of the elements. For this, I need to iteratively exclude one element. Specifically, I want to calculate the mean of all elements when one value is removed. E.g.:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Mean values:

```
[2, 3, 4] = 3      (excludes 1)
[1, 3, 4] = 2.66   (excludes 2)
[1, 2, 4] = 2.44   (excludes 3)
[1, 2, 3] = 2      (excludes 4)
```

Is there an intuitive way of doing this, without something like

```
[mylist[i-1:i] + mylist[i+1:] for i in range(len(mylist))]?
```

Answer (score 7):

Maths to the rescue!

The mean of a list is `sum(myList) / len(myList)`.

If you remove an element `x` from `myList`, the sum becomes `sum(myList) - x`. Now the mean of the remaining elements is `(sum(myList) - x) / (len(myList) - 1)`

For all elements:

```
newList = [(sum(myList) - x) / (len(myList) - 1) for x in myList]
```

Or for O(n),

```
s = sum(myList)
newLen = len(myList) - 1 
newList = [(s - x) / newLen for x in myList]
```

Comment: Good. Now in order to make this O(n) instead of O(n^2), store `sum(myList)` in a variable, `len(myList)` is ok because it is stored as an attribute on the list, but storing it in a variable will save the overhead of calling a function.

Comment: @DeepSpace, I was about to edit the initial answer to add that in! Thanks :-)

Comment: Excellent example of how to break down the problem to basic fundamentals.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way using a `collections.deque` and "rotate" it, and removing the first element at every iteration of the loop:

```
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]

from collections import deque

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    d = deque(mylist)
    d.rotate(-i)
    first, *rest = d
    print(f'{rest}: {sum(rest)/len(rest):.2f}')
```

```
[2, 3, 4]: 3.00
[3, 4, 1]: 2.67
[4, 1, 2]: 2.33
[1, 2, 3]: 2.00
```

Comment: TBH, answer by @PranavHosangadi is much easier to read/interpret (i.e. Pythonic).

Comment: @S3DEV This answer is still useful though, if the objective is something other than taking the mean, or if you want to print the modified list.

Comment: I know, that's why I voted it up. But I suck at math so this is the way I found while working on this problem.

Comment: Fair play to you both.  I’ve learned from both, thanks and good work!